# Как сделать нагрузочное тестирование своего сайта?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, тестирование

Например, интересует максимальное количество одновременных запросов подключений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[apache benchmarks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)

для эмуляции сотни подключений одновременно и выполнения тысячи запросов всего:

```
ab -c 100 -n 1000 example.com/
```

Отмечу, что у меня не хотел работать до тех пор, пока я не поставил слеш в конце, т.е. на `example.com` выдавалась ошибка о неправильном URL, а `example.com/` уже норм.

Установка в линуксе - `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils`, под виндой - не знаю.

Comment: Я опробовал на своём сайте. Результат 63 запроса в секунду. Это много или мало?

Comment: Если там делается тяжелая работа, то нормально. Но если это главная страница сайта и там все - статика, а сайт планируется быть посещаемым, то, может, и мало.

Comment: Обратите внимание (из доки по url-ю)

    The rather heavy use of strstr(3) shows up top in profile, which might indicate a performance problem; i.e., you would measure the ab performance rather than the server's.